# Как принять в список форматированный вывод списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, список

Как разделить вот такую строку

```
s = '[7, 9, 9, 8, 7],[7, 8, 9, 8, 9],[8, 8, 6, 2, 4, 3]'
```

в двумерный список?

Comment: `ast.literal_eval("[" + s + "]")`, либо `list(ast.literal_eval(s))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для таких целей можно воспользоваться регулярными выражениями (модуль `re`).

Поиск по шаблону `\[([^\[\]]*)\]*` вернёт следующий список:

```py
['7, 9, 9, 8, 7', '7, 8, 9, 8, 9', '8, 8, 6, 2, 4, 3']
```

Далее можно разделить полученные строки по запятым с помощью `split(',')`.
А полученные числа привести к типу `int`.

***Пример:***

```py
import re


def main():
    s = '[7, 9, 9, 8, 7],[7, 8, 9, 8, 9],[8, 8, 6, 2, 4, 3]'

    matrix = [list(map(int, li.split(','))) for li in re.findall(r'\[([^\[\]]*)\]*', s)]
    print(matrix)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

***stdout:***

```py
[[7, 9, 9, 8, 7], [7, 8, 9, 8, 9], [8, 8, 6, 2, 4, 3]]
```

---

Есть ещё один довольно короткий, но опасный способ — функция `eval`.

Использовать стоит только тогда, когда Вы уверены в безопасности и корректности передаваемых данных!
В большинстве случаев данный подход делает Вашу программу ***уязвимой к исполнению произвольного кода***!

***Пример:***

```py
...
matrix = list(eval(s))
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = '[7, 9, 9, 8, 7],[7, 8, 9, 8, 9],[8, 8, 6, 2, 4, 3]'
s2 = []
for i in s[1:][:-1].split('],['):
    s2.append(i.split(',') )
print(s2)
```

Вывод:

```
[['7', ' 9', ' 9', ' 8', ' 7'], ['7', ' 8', ' 9', ' 8', ' 9'], ['8', ' 8', ' 6', ' 2', ' 4', ' 3']]
```